# how to separate white guassian noise from signal in foureir domain

Tags: image-processing, signals, signal-processing, continuous-fourier, wiener-filter

i have a signal with added white gaussian noise. i m doing some kind of mode decomposition. After mode decomposition the noise does not look random but have streaks like appearance in time domain. The mode decomposition is a wiener filter and it does linear decomposition. So it transforms the white noise as linear streaks. Please see the noise in frequency domain. The red is the signal and the output mode in blue has noise in it. I appreciate assistance
[image]
thanks
sal

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking. Your filter is enhancing existing noise? Or is it inventing noise? Why not post a [mre]? There are many noise reduction filters. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: thanks. my filter changes random noise into amall streaks. the filter is a wiener filter which decompose data into linear patterns. In the process it makes random noise into streaks. I tried entropy, but since it is no more guassain, it is  not the right answer. i m studying cumulants. but not sure how they will work. i already tried kurtosis. but it turned out thatsignal and noise havesame localize tail distribution.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you are asking. What would a useful answer look like? Without seeing your code, I’m not sure anyone could actually help. If you are looking for a theoretical answer, maybe ask over at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ because signal processing theory is not really on topic here, SO is for questions about programming.

Comment: That said, my original suggestion was to apply a noise reduction filter **before** applying your filter, this maybe would suppress the noise sufficiently.